# ul li drop-down menu partly behind an image and not positioned evenly

Tags: html, css

This simple page is giving me headaches. Site structure is simple: nav bar as head and the main content area is comprised by a big image and two paragraphs; and a footer at the bottom —that's all.

I've got the following problems:

1. part of that drop-down menu appears behind the big image(1135x307). I want it to appear on the front.
2. the nav bar items are not positioned evenly. I want them to appear evenly on top of the image below.
3. the footer needs to go further down even when there's not much content in the main content area. I don't know how to make this happen.

Here's the link to the html and css code: http://jsbin.com/loponi/1/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `z-index` on your `ul` :

```
.topNav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**UPDATED**

I dont know how it is but try to make these changes:

Wrap your contents paragraph inside a div:

```
<div class="contentArea">
  //  all <p class="content">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentArea { width: 1135px; min-height:500px;height:auto;}
.content {
    width:100%;
 }
.footer{    
  bottom:0;      
 }
```

Hope this will help you..

[CHECK THIS](http://jsbin.com/fubud/2)

Comment: That certainly worked, thanks a lot Shail! btw, could you also help me with the other two questions? I want the nav bar to be positioned evenly based on the width of the hero image, how can I do that? And how can I push the footer further down? Much appreciated!

Comment: can you fix your `jsbin` link first, its not working?

Comment: here's the working link: http://jsbin.com/loponi/1/edit?html,css,js,output thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Image in your JSBIN is not working...

But you can try to add `position: relative;` to your `nav`. 
If this doesn't help, set `z-index` for your nav as well.